# java for loop factors program

Tags: java, loops, factors

Hi I have to make a program(java) on which you input a number and it outputs the number of factors it has(EX: 4 ---> 3)

Code:

```
package Class;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Profgrams {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter the number;");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    long n = scan.nextLong();

    for(int i=1, f=0; i <= n; i++){ 
        if(n % i == 0){
            f++;
        }
        System.out.println(f);
    }

    }

}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you explain what the issue with your program is? Is the output incorrect? Are you getting an error?

Comment: the output is incorrect EX (4 --> 1223)

Comment: it prints each on a separate line

Comment: That's because `System.out.println(f)` is inside your `for` loop, so it's printing `f` each time it runs through the loop. Move that outside of the loop, and declare `f` before the loop so it can be used outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Declare and initialize `f` before the loop, and then print the result after the loop terminates. That way printing will not occur at each iteration of the loop.

```
int f = 0;
// ...
System.out.println(f);
```

Comment: I did and it comes out the same

Comment: Remove the print statement inside the loop.